# Calculate the amount of array content in the VB.Net Console

Tags: vb.net, console-application

I'm use Console Program in VB.Net

I have data : [image: Data]

How to create if i choose HONDA the result is 3670. AND OR

if i choose APR the result is 1750 and the average of data is 350

Please anybody help me.

Comment: Please don't post images of sample data. Not everyone can see the image, and even for those who can it makes it much harder for them to help you. You will get a much better answer faster if you take the time to provide the data in a text table.

Comment: Also, show what you have so far in terms of user interface and data loading... how will the user make the selection? How are you pulling this data right now? We need a starting point in order to provide a meaningful answer.

Comment: Datatable for example, then select by row or column.

Comment: Are these values hard-coded in the application or are they retrieved or read from somewhere?

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned array in the title, but I personally wouldn't use an array for this. I will show you why. See the following examples and read the comments within.

Option 1. Multidimensional array

```vb
Dim data As Integer(,) = {
    {150, 200, 100, 300, 250, 400, 500, 450, 350, 220, 150, 600},
    {400, 500, 450, 350, 220, 150, 600, 150, 200, 100, 300, 250},
    {300, 250, 400, 500, 450, 350, 150, 200, 100, 300, 450, 400},
    {250, 220, 450, 100, 450, 400, 350, 200, 100, 100, 450, 400},
    {100, 450, 400, 500, 600, 150, 350, 220, 100, 300, 100, 250}}
Dim HONDA_sum As Integer
Dim APR_sum As Integer
Dim APR_avg As Double
For i = 0 To UBound(data, 2)
    HONDA_sum += data(1, i)
Next
For i = 0 To UBound(data, 1)
    APR_sum += data(i, 3)
    APR_avg = (APR_avg * i + data(i, 3)) / (i + 1)
Next
' For loops are used because multidimensional arrays aren't great with LINQ
' YAMAHA row is 1. You need to hard-code this or make a lookup table
' APR column is 3. You need to hard-code this or make a lookup table
' avg arithmetic is a little complicated
```

Option 2. Jagged array

```vb
Dim data As Integer()() = {
        New Integer() {150, 200, 100, 300, 250, 400, 500, 450, 350, 220, 150, 600},
        New Integer() {400, 500, 450, 350, 220, 150, 600, 150, 200, 100, 300, 250},
        New Integer() {300, 250, 400, 500, 450, 350, 150, 200, 100, 300, 450, 400},
        New Integer() {250, 220, 450, 100, 450, 400, 350, 200, 100, 100, 450, 400},
        New Integer() {100, 450, 400, 500, 600, 150, 350, 220, 100, 300, 100, 250}}
Dim HONDA_sum = data(1).Sum()
Dim APR_sum = data.Sum(Function(l) l(3))
Dim APR_avg = data.Average(Function(l) l(3))
' We can use LINQ but some hard-coded column numbers are used
' YAMAHA row is 1. You need to hard-code this or make a lookup table
' APR column is 3. You need to hard-code this or make a lookup table
```

Option 3. Dictionary(Of Dictionary)

```vb
Dim data As New Dictionary(Of String, Dictionary(Of String, Integer)) From {
    {"YAMAHA", New Dictionary(Of String, Integer) From {{"JAN", 150}, {"FEB", 200}, {"MAR", 100}, {"APR", 300}, {"MAY", 250}, {"JUN", 400}, {"JUL", 500}, {"AUG", 450}, {"SEP", 350}, {"OCT", 220}, {"NOV", 150}, {"DEC", 600}}},
    {"HONDA", New Dictionary(Of String, Integer) From {{"JAN", 400}, {"FEB", 500}, {"MAR", 450}, {"APR", 350}, {"MAY", 220}, {"JUN", 150}, {"JUL", 600}, {"AUG", 150}, {"SEP", 200}, {"OCT", 100}, {"NOV", 300}, {"DEC", 250}}},
    {"SUZUKI", New Dictionary(Of String, Integer) From {{"JAN", 300}, {"FEB", 250}, {"MAR", 400}, {"APR", 500}, {"MAY", 450}, {"JUN", 350}, {"JUL", 150}, {"AUG", 200}, {"SEP", 100}, {"OCT", 300}, {"NOV", 450}, {"DEC", 400}}},
    {"KAWASAKI", New Dictionary(Of String, Integer) From {{"JAN", 250}, {"FEB", 220}, {"MAR", 450}, {"APR", 100}, {"MAY", 450}, {"JUN", 400}, {"JUL", 350}, {"AUG", 200}, {"SEP", 100}, {"OCT", 100}, {"NOV", 450}, {"DEC", 400}}},
    {"MINERVA", New Dictionary(Of String, Integer) From {{"JAN", 100}, {"FEB", 450}, {"MAR", 400}, {"APR", 500}, {"MAY", 600}, {"JUN", 150}, {"JUL", 350}, {"AUG", 220}, {"SEP", 100}, {"OCT", 300}, {"NOV", 100}, {"DEC", 250}}}
}
Dim HONDA_sum = data("HONDA").Sum(Function(kvp) kvp.Value)
Dim APR_sum = data.Values.Select(Function(d) d("APR")).Sum()
Dim APR_avg = data.Values.Select(Function(d) d("APR")).Average()
' A little better. Again we can use LINQ and the data can be addressed with manufacturer or month names
' but it's still clumsy to define your data in code like this
```

Option 3.5 List

Not implemented because it's similar to the jagged array and I'd prefer Dictionaries anyway.

Option 4. List(Of Tuple)

```vb
Dim data As New List(Of (Manufacturer As String, Month As String, Total As Integer)) From {
    ("YAMAHA", "JAN", 150), ("YAMAHA", "FEB", 200), ("YAMAHA", "MAR", 100), ("YAMAHA", "APR", 300), ("YAMAHA", "MAY", 250), ("YAMAHA", "JUN", 400), ("YAMAHA", "JUL", 500), ("YAMAHA", "AUG", 450), ("YAMAHA", "SEP", 350), ("YAMAHA", "OCT", 220), ("YAMAHA", "NOV", 150), ("YAMAHA", "DEC", 600),
    ("HONDA", "JAN", 400), ("HONDA", "FEB", 500), ("HONDA", "MAR", 450), ("HONDA", "APR", 350), ("HONDA", "MAY", 220), ("HONDA", "JUN", 150), ("HONDA", "JUL", 600), ("HONDA", "AUG", 150), ("HONDA", "SEP", 200), ("HONDA", "OCT", 100), ("HONDA", "NOV", 300), ("HONDA", "DEC", 250),
    ("SUZUKI", "JAN", 300), ("SUZUKI", "FEB", 250), ("SUZUKI", "MAR", 400), ("SUZUKI", "APR", 500), ("SUZUKI", "MAY", 450), ("SUZUKI", "JUN", 350), ("SUZUKI", "JUL", 150), ("SUZUKI", "AUG", 200), ("SUZUKI", "SEP", 100), ("SUZUKI", "OCT", 300), ("SUZUKI", "NOV", 450), ("SUZUKI", "DEC", 400),
    ("KAWASAKI", "JAN", 250), ("KAWASAKI", "FEB", 220), ("KAWASAKI", "MAR", 450), ("KAWASAKI", "APR", 100), ("KAWASAKI", "MAY", 450), ("KAWASAKI", "JUN", 400), ("KAWASAKI", "JUL", 350), ("KAWASAKI", "AUG", 200), ("KAWASAKI", "SEP", 100), ("KAWASAKI", "OCT", 100), ("KAWASAKI", "NOV", 450), ("KAWASAKI", "DEC", 400),
    ("MINERVA", "JAN", 100), ("MINERVA", "FEB", 450), ("MINERVA", "MAR", 400), ("MINERVA", "APR", 500), ("MINERVA", "MAY", 600), ("MINERVA", "JUN", 150), ("MINERVA", "JUL", 350), ("MINERVA", "AUG", 220), ("MINERVA", "SEP", 100), ("MINERVA", "OCT", 300), ("MINERVA", "NOV", 100), ("MINERVA", "DEC", 250)}
Dim HONDA_sum = data.Where(Function(t) t.Manufacturer = "HONDA").Sum(Function(t) t.Total)
Dim APR_sum = data.Where(Function(t) t.Month = "APR").Sum(Function(t) t.Total)
Dim APR_avg = data.Where(Function(t) t.Month = "APR").Average(Function(t) t.Total)
' Another method which allows for LINQ. The queries are nice and clean. This method feels like querying SQL...
' but it's a nightmare to maintain this data import similar to the previous methods
```

Option 5. ORM

```vb
Using dc As New DataContext()
    Dim HONDA_sum = (From d In dc.Datas Where d.Manufacturer = "HONDA" Select d.Total).Sum()
    Dim APR_sum = (From d In dc.Datas Where d.Month = "APR" Select d.Total).Sum()
    Dim APR_avg = (From d In dc.Datas Where d.Month = "APR" Select d.Total).Average()
End Using
' This is hypothetical, but assuming your data is in a database table with columns
' Table: Data
' Columns: Month (string), Manufacturer (string), Total (integer)
' and you have used EF or LinqToSQL to generate an ORM
' this allows a very clean implementation using a standard language i.e. LINQ / SQL
' Expression LINQ or Lambdas can be used, both resulting in the same underlying query
```

I recommend Option 5 if you have a database. This can also be done with something like Excel or even a text file but the nice thing about it is once you set up your entity mapping (ideally with IDE tools...) the same code can apply to whatever your data source is.

With the exception of Option 5, where this is N/A, you may notice that as the data import gets more complex, the data retrieval gets simpler. This is a tradeoff you need to consider <strike>when</strike> before you develop your app.

Comment: Big thanks to you for the answer. Sure i choose option 1 and i was create it.

Comment: 1 more question again, what function for exit the application in Console VB.Net ?? Console.(what?)

Answer (score 0):

When I see a table of data, I think DataTable. Easy to build and lots of things you can do with it. So, I have another option in addition to the options provided by @djv.

```vb
Private Sub OPCode()
    'Build the DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataTable
    With dt.Columns
        .Add("Brand", GetType(String))
        .Add("Jan", GetType(Integer))
        .Add("Feb", GetType(Integer))
        .Add("Mar", GetType(Integer))
        .Add("Apr", GetType(Integer))
        .Add("May", GetType(Integer))
        .Add("Jun", GetType(Integer))
        .Add("Jul", GetType(Integer))
        .Add("Aug", GetType(Integer))
        .Add("Sep", GetType(Integer))
        .Add("Oct", GetType(Integer))
        .Add("Nov", GetType(Integer))
        .Add("Dec", GetType(Integer))
        'The last 2 columns are computed by the DataTable according to the expression provided
        .Add("Total", GetType(Integer), "Jan + Feb + Mar + Apr + May + Jun + Jul + Aug + Sep + Oct + Nov + Dec")
        .Add("Average", GetType(Decimal), "Total/12")
    End With
    'Add the data with object arrays
    With dt.Rows
        .Add({"Yamaha", 150, 200, 100, 300, 250, 400, 500, 450, 350, 220, 150, 600})
        .Add({"HONDA", 400, 500, 450, 350, 220, 150, 600, 150, 200, 100, 300, 250})
        .Add({"SUZUKI", 300, 250, 400, 500, 450, 350, 150, 200, 100, 300, 450, 400})
        .Add({"KAWASAKI", 250, 220, 450, 100, 450, 400, 350, 200, 100, 100, 450, 400})
        .Add({"MINERVA", 100, 450, 400, 500, 600, 150, 350, 220, 100, 300, 100, 250})
    End With
    'Display the results
    For ColumnIndex = 1 To 12
        Dim ColumnName = dt.Columns(ColumnIndex).ColumnName
        Dim Total = dt.Compute($"Sum({ColumnName})", Nothing)
        Console.WriteLine($"Total for {ColumnName} is {Total}")
        Dim Average = dt.Compute($"Avg({ColumnName})", Nothing)
        Console.WriteLine($"Average of Brands for {ColumnName} is {Average}")
    Next
    For Each row As DataRow In dt.Rows
        Console.WriteLine($"The Total for {row("Brand")} is {row("Total")}")
        Console.WriteLine($"The Average per month for {row("Brand")} is {row("Average"):N0}")
    Next

End Sub
```

If this code was moved to a WinForms project your could display it quickly with

```
DataGridView1.DataSource = dt
```